# Search in database with values of String array (filter list view with multi data for a specific column)

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app I implement custom listView filter that user can search in it with the value of a textView.

But in this situation I have an array of names that want to limit the items in listview to these names. But I don't know how to fetch records that their names is in this array.

I write the where statement for a single value like this :

```
 buf.append(Imps.Contacts.NICKNAME);
                buf.append(" LIKE ");
                DatabaseUtils.appendValueToSql(buf, "%" + mSearchString + "%");
                buf.append(" OR ");
                buf.append(Imps.Contacts.USERNAME);
                buf.append(" LIKE ");
                DatabaseUtils.appendValueToSql(buf, "%" + mSearchString + "%");
```

But in this case `mSearchString` is an array of string not a single string.
I hope I explain my problem clearly :)

**UPDATE:**

I'm looking for a SQL statement like  `FIND_IN_SET` in MySQL that work with SQLite too.

Comment: What do you mean by "i have an Array of names that want to limit the items in listView to these names"?

Comment: lets me explain it : i have a listview that show some names , in first model user can type a name and this list display similar names from DB. but now i have an array of names (i get them from db) for eg 6 names in an array , then i want to fetch data about these 6 name and display them to user

Comment: Are you using rawQuery()?

Comment: No , im using db.query finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean :

```
buf.append(Imps.Contacts.NICKNAME);
buf.append(" LIKE ");
DatabaseUtils.appendValueToSql(buf, "%" + aString + "%");
for (int i = 0; i != mSearchString.length;i++) {
    buf.append(" OR ");
    buf.append(Imps.Contacts.USERNAME);
    buf.append(" LIKE ");
    DatabaseUtils.appendValueToSql(buf, "%" + mSearchString[i] + "%");
}
```

Comment: I think about this solution but im not sure its a good approach :/

Comment: I could not find better solution , i change your answer abit and use it . thanks :)